# Are there native C++ (not C) interfaces for Blas and Lapack libraries?

Tags: c++, lapack, blas

Currently, there are:

- **cblas** which is shipped with [blas](http://www.netlib.org/blas/),
- **lapacke** which is shipped with [lapack](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/),

however, these are C interfaces.

Obviously, you can use them in a C++ code, but you do not get all the benefits you would get if these interfaces were designed for C++. So my question is:
**are such interfaces exist in native C++?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recently these two interfaces, from University of Tennessee, has been released:

- https://bitbucket.org/icl/blaspp
- https://bitbucket.org/icl/lapackpp

There are some immediate benefits of using these native C++ implementations.

Let's consider a basic generic programming example:

Imagine that you want to scale a vector: `v = alpha*v` thanks to the [cblas_?scal](https://software.intel.com/en-us/mkl-developer-reference-c-cblas-scal) functions.

**With cblas**, if you wanted something "generic" in the sense that it has the same interface for all supported scalar types (`float`, `double`, `complex<float>`, `complex<double>`,...), all the C functions had to be wrapped:

```
void scal(cblas_int n,float alpha, float *x, cblas_int inc) {
    ...
    cblas_sscal(n,alpha,x,inc);  <- s for float
}

void scal(cblas_int n,double alpha, double *x, cblas_int inc) {
    ...
    cblas_dscal(n,alpha,x,inc);  <- d for double
}

// do the same for complex<float>, complex<double> ...
```

The reason is that in C, two functions are differents if they have different **names**: `cblas_sscal`, `cblas_dscal`...
In C++ you can have the same name **scal** and this is the compiler job to  dispatch to the right function according to its arguments, here `float`, `double`...

**The situation now.** With the mentioned https://bitbucket.org/icl/blaspp C++ native interface this boilerplate code has already been written once for all. For instance if you look [scal.hh](https://bitbucket.org/icl/blaspp/src/a1ac68dc490ba96e4fcbfbdd502481e91ec9dda4/include/scal.hh?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default) header file you have:

```
void scal(int64_t n, float alpha, float *x, int64_t incx ) { ... }
void scal(int64_t n, double alpha, double *x, int64_t incx ) { ... }
void scal(int64_t n, std:complex<float> alpha, std:complex<float> *x, int64_t incx ) { ... }
void scal(int64_t n, std:complex<double> alpha, std:complex<double> *x, int64_t incx ) { ... }
```

and even a generic implementation:

```
template<typename T>
void scal(int64_t n, T alpha, T *x, int64_t incx ) { ... }
```

Hence with this C++ interface, it is easy to define a generic interface for your favorit vector/matrix type. As example, with `std::vector<T>`, you only have to write (independently of the actual T type):

```
template<typename T>
void scal(T alpha, std::vector<T>& v) {
   scal(v.size(),alpha,v.data(),1);
}
```

**No more boilerplate code!**

---

This is the idea, however note that:

- generic implementation are not yet implemented for all subroutines, for instance:

.

```
template< typename TA, typename TX >
void trmm(
    blas::Layout layout,
    blas::Side side,
    blas::Uplo uplo,
    blas::Op trans,
    blas::Diag diag,
    int64_t m,
    int64_t n,
    typename blas::traits2<TA, TX>::scalar_t alpha,
    TA const *A, int64_t lda,
    TX       *B, int64_t ldb )
{
    throw std::exception();  // not yet implemented
}
```

- The previous example used **blas**, however, it is even more interesting for **lapack** which has several hundreds of wrapped subroutines.

Comment: I had a mini heart-attack when I saw that someone wrote this big answer to a question that was asked 1 minute ago.

Comment: @Yashas I write some notes for myself here, however, maybe they can be useful for others, this is the idea :-).

Answer (score 2):

It is not exactly what you seek, but would suggest [Blaze C++ library](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze):

> Blaze is an open-source, high-performance C++ math library for dense
>   and sparse arithmetic. With its state-of-the-art Smart Expression
>   Template implementation Blaze combines the elegance and ease of use of
>   a domain-specific language with HPC-grade performance, making it one
>   of the most intuitive and fastest C++ math libraries available.
>
> The Blaze library offers ...
>
> - ... high performance through the integration of BLAS libraries and manually tuned HPC math kernels
> - ... vectorization by SSE, SSE2, SSE3, SSSE3, SSE4, AVX, AVX2, AVX-512, FMA, and SVML
> - ... parallel execution by OpenMP, C++11 threads and Boost threads
> - ... the intuitive and easy to use API of a domain specific language
> - ... unified arithmetic with dense and sparse vectors and matrices
> - ... thoroughly tested matrix and vector arithmetic
> - ... completely portable, high quality C++ source code

Wiki has lists of [BLAS](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze/wiki/BLAS%20Functions) and [LAPACK](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze/wiki/LAPACK%20Functions) functions supported.

I did not use it myself, but [benchmarks](https://bitbucket.org/blaze-lib/blaze/wiki/Benchmarks) show, that this library performs very well. The development community is very friendly and is open for discussion.

Comment: yes, I am aware of Blaze, Eigen, Armadillo,... libraries. However, sometimes  I prefer a flat interface, without the [Expression Template Mechanism](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=06266939). Reason: simpler code and reduced compilation time :). Thanks for completing my answer anyway :)